# What is "reload()" for in MongoEngine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have a statement like: `jsonify_ok(data=mytag.reload().as_dict())`

What role does reload() play? what's the normal situation for us to use reload()?

Comment: Refer to MongoEngine 0.15.0 API Document

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Document.reload()` will check the database and update your data (I think in this case `mytag` but I can't see what this is) with any attributes that have been modified.

This could be useful if the data could or has changed before calling `jsonify_ok`.

Breaking down your `data=mytag.reload()` this says: "For document `mytag`, go to the database and fetch the latest version of this document, assigning this to variable `data`"

[Relevant documentation link](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.reload)

Comment: thanks a lot! could u please help me up one score to my question? thanks!