# Await mongoengine update in python

Tags: python, mongodb

I would like to await the inbuilt function `update` from `mongoengine` to pull some data from an object and then afterwards run a function that checks the effect of the executed query.

```
def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Keyword, self).update(*args, **kwargs) # Wait for this to execute
    self.set_deleted() # Then run these 2
    self.save()
```

I know that in node I could declare the function `async` and then just `await` the super call. 
Is there any way I can force my model function to await the super call or have a callback like system in which I can execute `self.set_deleted()` right after the super call?

If possible I would like to avoid having to declare all functions that use the update function as async, something like a promise callback would be appropriate if that is a thing in python.

**State**:

**Before first run**:

length of arr = 5

deleted = false

**After first run**:

length of arr = 0

deleted = false  # This should already be true at this point

**After second run**:

length of arr = 0

deleted = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the Problem is that a reload was needed and that can be achieve with the reload function in mongoengine. Link to the docs: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.reload

and here is another Description found here:[What is "reload()" for in MongoEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419456/what-is-reload-for-in-mongoengine)

Document.reload() will check the database and update your data (I think in this case mytag but I can't see what this is) with any attributes that have been modified.

This could be useful if the data could or has changed before calling jsonify_ok.

Breaking down your data=mytag.reload() this says: "For document mytag, go to the database and fetch the latest version of this document, assigning this to variable data"

Comment: I have had a look at that but it seems like I would need to perform some major changes in my app to add the library. I am looking for a solution that might be as simple as a callback if such thing exists.

Comment: Ok but what's the Problem with your code there ? python interpreter will call that function until it finish and then go to the other function since you are not using asynchronous there. Can you explain how your code behave in your actuel situation

Comment: The update function itself will remove elements from an array. My `set_deleted` function will then check if said array is of length 0 and then set a deleted flag to `true`. When I run this code the array is being emptied by the update function but the deleted flag is not set to `true`. When I run the function again the deleted flag is set to `true` which makes me think that it has to do with `set_deleted` being executed before `update` finished (I added state to my question)

Comment: Tried it, same issue as before.

Comment: hmmm I don't think anyway that it has something to do with what you are saying because python is not asynchronous by nature. there is no way that it will jump to execute the other function before the first one. hope this helps you debugging at least

Comment: maybe you need to reload or refresh after calling the update function on mongoengine then

Comment: yes you can use reload function to reload a document in mongoengine. here is the docs: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.reload

Comment: great ;). I ll update the answers for future search

Comment: maybe you can please accept the answer so that it helps someone when he search for the same Problem and could easily find the solution. thnx ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem.

The issue seems to be, that the update function is ran and python even awaits said function but when I call my `set_deleted` function it still uses the old Document with the old data, not the new updated version of the document.

adding `self = Keyword.objects.get(id=self.id)` after the super call did the trick.